# asp.net validators on windows 2008 server and internet explorer 11

Tags: asp.net, windows-server-2008, internet-explorer-11

I have asp.net 4.0 website that is working fine on development machine windows 7 i have

> required field validators

on one page, the validators works fine on the development.

After i deploy the website to development machine

> windows 2008 server

, when i access the page from chrome or firefox or internet explorer 9, it is working fine.

The problems starts when i access the website from internet explorer 11.

Any suggestions.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

i installed .net framework 4.5 and it is fixed.